# Create html table which is depend on dropdown selection

Tags: java

I have one dropdown list which is populated from database table.Now i want table 
values from same database table which depend on dropdown selection.
Write code in jsp

Comment: what is your problem ? first write a code and then describe problem here.

Comment: <select id="device_id" name="device_id" onchange="showRows(this)" >                                              
        <%  while(resultSet.next()){ %>
            <option><%= resultSet.getString("device_id")%></option>
        <% } %>
        </select>

Comment: you can submit the form and get "device_id" from the request. this gives you selected value of your table.

Comment: how to write it  in code .Please help me ,i m new in jsp code.

Comment: check the answer please.

Answer (score -1):

first of all make a html form which contains your list, like this :

**form.jsp**

```
<form action="result.jsp">
  <select name="myList">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

after form submission you can get selected list value using :`<%=request.getParameter("myList")%>;`

```
<%String selectedVal = request.getParameter("myList");%>
```

now dataTbl is your selected table row value now you can populate database table using a simple query and do what you want with that.
you need something like this :
**result.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>SELECT Operation</title>
</head>
<body>

<sql:setDataSource var="ds" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/TEST"
   user="root"  password="pass123"/>

<sql:query dataSource="${ds}" var="result">
     SELECT * from Employees  WHERE Id = ?
     <sql:param value="${selectedVal}" />;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
     <th>Emp ID</th>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>
     <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
  <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

desciption : first of all we get the value from form.jsp which was selected row by user and we connected to database using sql tag then run our query on the database with where clause and selectedValue as a parameter for query.
then show specific table data based on selected row by user (SelectedVal) and iterate through table records using a for tag.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Your answer is on right track for me.But table values are not populating from databse.I want this by using resultset prepared statement.

Comment: why you need prepared statement and resultset ?! this is easier way to connect to db from jsp. please mark as an answer.